# How can I extract an specific information from an yml file in Python and use it in a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dictionary, yaml

I've received a Pandas dataframe which was a YML. I've already imported like this:

```
with open('file_name.yml') as f:
yml_data = yaml.load(f, Loader=yaml.FullLoader)
```

Besides this data, I have another one in a dataframe format, let's call it `table_1`, and this table looks like this:

```
col1    id
AA      1
BB      2
CC      2
DD      3
EE      15
FF      5
```

I want to check if every id in `table_1` is in yml_data.

I've thought about converting `table_1` into a dataframe, but after using `pd.from_dict`, I got this weird dataframe (I'll show only two rows here as an example, but there are of course several):

```
col1 
{'title': 'This is the first title', 'message': 'This is the first message', 
'groups': [{'title': 'Another title', 'message': 'Another message', 
'ids': [1, 10, 20]}, {'title': 'One more title', 'message': 'another message', 
'ids': [2, 3, 4, 5]}}
{'title': 'This is the first title of the 2nd element', 'message': 'This is the first 
message of the 2nd element','groups': [{'title': 'Another title', 'message': 'Another 
message', 'ids': [1000, 9, 8]}, {'title': 'One more title', 'message': 'another 
message','ids': [12, 13, 14, 15]}, {'title': 'One more title', 'message': 'another 
message','ids': [120, 130, 140, 150]}}
```

All ids from `table_1` must be in the yml_data. Can someone help me to find a way of doing this?

UPDATE: I was thinking about converting table_1 and yml_data into text. So I did this for table_1, and tried to do for yml_data, after converting it into a dataframe. Basically, this is what I've done:

```
# convert table_1.id into text
table_1_id_text = ' '
for i in table_1[table_1.id.notna()].id:
table_1_id_text = table_1_id_text + ' ' + i

# convert yml data into dataframe(the result was the one above)
yml_df = pd.from_dict(yml_data)

# convert into text
yml_text = ' '
for i in yml_d[yml_df.col1.notna()].col1:
yml_text = yml_text + ' ' + i
```

For table_1 everything was fine (id is already a string). But I got the error for yml_text: TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "dict") to str. Also, even after doing that I'm not sure exactly how to check if all words from table